# Python: Converting list of xy coordinates into an adjacency list

Tags: python, graph, coordinates, adjacency-list

I have a list of tuples representing xy coordinates i.e.

```
coordinates = [(1, 0), (1, 1), (7, 1), (1, 2), (2, 2), (3, 2), (4, 2), (6, 2), (7, 2), (4, 3)]
```

each coordinate represents a node in a graph at that position which is connected to other nodes only if they are adjacent in the x or y direction, diagonals are not included. For example, in the coordinates list the (1,0) and (1,1) elements should be connected as they would be adjacent in the y direction.

I'm looking to create an adjacency list for this so I can run bfs and find the shortest path between nodes but I'm having trouble doing so as I'm not sure how I can compare each tuple with every other tuple in the list to find adjacent elements.

The end result would look like

```
adjacency_list = {1: [2], 2[1, 3], ... }
```

This would be for a node 1 with an edge to node 2 which has edges to nodes 1 and 3. All edges would be unweighted and undirected.

Comment: Thought you couldn't, as when I tried passing it to a defaultdict you get a `first argument must be callable or None` error message?

Comment: OP it seems like you're desired result doesn't match your described algorithm (unless I misunderstand)

Comment: @jdehesa thanks but that doesn't give a correct adjacency list, it just groups by common elements in the tuples. E.g. `{1: [0, 1, 6]}`. This is wrong as a node at (1,1) should be connected to a node at (1,0) but not at (1,6) as they're not adjacent

Comment: @BrianJoseph Sorry if I'm misunderstanding as well but I don't think I've really described an algorithm as I'm not sure what it should be at the moment. I'm looking to return an adjacency list from a list of coordinates but I'm not sure how to

Comment: @R_J Sorry, I had misunderstood the problem.

Comment: Would `adjacency_list = {i: [j for j, (j1, j2) in coordinates if abs(i1 - j1) + abs(i2 - j2) == 1] for i, (i1, i2) in enumerate(coordinates)}` do what you want?

Answer (score 1):

```
adjacency_lists = defaultdict(set)

for ind, coord in enumerate(coordinates):
    for other_coord in coordinates[ind:]:
        if abs((coord[0] - other_coord[0])) <= 1 or abs((coord[1] - other_coord[1])) <= 1:
            adjacency_lists[coord].add(other_coord)
            adjacency_lists[other_coord].add(coord)



>> adjacency_lists

  {(1, 0): {(1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 2), (7, 1)},
(1, 1): {(1, 0),(1, 1),(1, 2),(2, 2),(3, 2),(4, 2),(6, 2),(7, 1),(7, 2)},
(7, 1): {(1, 0),(1, 1),(1, 2),(2, 2),(3, 2),(4, 2),(6, 2),(7, 1),(7, 2)},
(1, 2): {(1, 0),(1, 1),(1, 2),(2, 2),(3, 2),(4, 2),(4, 3),(6, 2),(7, 1),(7, 2)},
(2, 2): {(1, 0),(1, 1),(1, 2),(2, 2),(3, 2),(4, 2),(4, 3),(6, 2),(7, 1),(7, 2)},
(3, 2): {(1, 1),(1, 2),(2, 2),(3, 2),(4, 2),(4, 3),(6, 2),(7, 1),(7, 2)},(4, 2): {(1, 1),(1, 2),(2, 2),(3, 2),(4, 2),(4, 3),(6, 2),(7, 1),(7, 2)},
(6, 2): {(1, 1),(1, 2),(2, 2),(3, 2),(4, 2),(4, 3),(6, 2),(7, 1),(7, 2)},
(7, 2): {(1, 1),(1, 2),(2, 2),(3, 2),(4, 2),(4, 3),(6, 2),(7, 1),(7, 2)},
(4, 3): {(1, 2), (2, 2), (3, 2), (4, 2), (4, 3), (6, 2), (7, 2)}}
```